# Computing a large modular power

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you compute 4948^41 (mod 5963)? I tried to reduce the exponent to 32+8+1. However, I get stuck with the calculations and end up getting numbers that cannot fit in the calculator. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a calculator, your approach is fine.  Start by squaring $4948^2=24482704 \equiv 4589 \pmod {5963}$ That fits in an eight digit calculator.  Each square is reduced $\pmod {5963}$, so never exceeds eight digits.  Then multiplying up to get the $41$ power again fits, as long as you reduce each step along the way.  It is true, if you use a computer algebra system, you don't have to worry about that.   [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4948%5E41%20mod%205963) gets it in less than 4 seconds as well.

Comment: According to Alpha the answer is 4401. However my professor said that answer is wrong. So I'm still lost

Answer (score 0):

Use some compute algebra system. In Maple, 4948^41 mod 5963 returns 4401 in 4 secs (probably less, I did not time it).

Comment: wait so 4401 is the answer that appeared in 4 seconds?

Comment: yes 4401 is the answer

Comment: My professor says that 4401 is the wrong answer. So now I'm still lost

Comment: Alpha, http://m.wolframalpha.com/ gives the same answer as Maple, 4401, the command is Mod[x,y] to get x mod y. Try the calculator suggestion of the chosen answer to prove your professor wrong.